# What does size really mean in geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In both plots the points look different, but why?

```
mya <- data.frame(a=1:100)

ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=2, size=seq(0.1,10,0.1))) +
  geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=1, size=1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=11))

ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=2, size=1)) +
  geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=1, size=1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=11))
```

`?aes_linetype_size_shape` explains ...

```
 # Size examples
 # Should be specified with a numerical value (in millimetres),
 # or from a variable source
```

But in my code it looks different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of confusing things happening in your code. You seem to be using the `aes` function in a way that is not intended. As well as the `size` issue, you are getting multiple legends, and I think ggplot is confused about the colours.

The `aes` function is used to map aesthetics to variables in the data, but you are using it to set aesthetics to a constant. In addition, you are using the `aes` function to set two separate aesthetics. Even though you set `size` to a constant, ggplot2 does not like two separate (paths and points) size mappings. Further, you do the same with a colour mapping.

`size` and `colour` are set to constant values so move them outside the `aes` function.  Also, with respect to `size` of the path in the first plot, it is probably safer to add a `size` variable to the data frame. (I've modified your data a little so that both points and paths are visible.) And as expected, one legend in the first plot is drawn.

```
    library(ggplot2)
mya <- data.frame(a=1:10, size = seq(10, 1, -1))

ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, size=size), colour = 2) +
  geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a), colour = 1, size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=11))

ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a), colour = 2, size = 1) +
  geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a), colour = 1, size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=11))
```

[image]