# Does size for ggplot2::geom_point() refer to radius, diameter, area, or something else?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Though I have tried to research more into this question, I remain confused on what exactly the size parameter varies for geom_point() in ggplot2.  I've noticed that there are methods to force point sizes to specific radii (e.g., geforce::geom_circle()), yet for my own circumstances I need to know more explicitly what size alters for geom_point (radius, circumference, diameter, etc.?).  Below are just a few of the most relevant questions related to this topic, but none seem to provide an exact answer.  I'm also aware that size for geom_point() may be relative rather than absolute, but some validation of this would be nice.

[Increasing minimum point size in ggplot geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809824/increasing-minimum-point-size-in-ggplot-geom-point)

[What does size really mean in geom_point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548321/what-does-size-really-mean-in-geom-point)

[ggplot geom_point varying size with windows size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633539/ggplot-geom-point-varying-size-with-windows-size)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `geom_point`, the size parameter scales both the x and y dimension of the point proportionately. This means if you double the size, the radius will double. If the radius doubles, so will the circumference and the diameter. However, since the *area* of the shape is proportional to the square of its radius, if you double the size, the area will actually increase by a factor of 4. We can see this with a simple experimental plot:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x     = 0.5, 
                  y     = 0.5, 
                  panel = c("A", "B"), 
                  size = c(20, 40))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, size = size)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  facet_wrap(.~panel) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

We can see from the gridlines that the shape with a size of 20 is exactly half the width of the shape with a size of 40. However, the larger shape takes up 4 times as much space on the plot.

That is why we need to be careful if we are using `size` to represent a variable; a point with twice the `size` gives the impression of being 4 times larger. To compensate for this, we can multiply our initial size by `sqrt(2)` instead of by 2 to give a more realistic visual impression:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x     = 0.5, 
                  y     = 0.5, 
                  panel = c("A", "B"), 
                  size = c(20, 20 * sqrt(2)))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, size = size)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  facet_wrap(.~panel) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Now the larger point has twice the *area* of the smaller point.