# Scale the start- and end-point of the edge against the connected node size in the network plot using R

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

Thanks for your help in advance!

My question is, given a list of sets, how can I visualize the overlap of any of the two sets using the network plot as shown below?

[image: An image to illustrate the question]

Please feel free to generate any sets for demonstration. Or you can use the following simple sets.

```
set.seed(123456)
A <- sample(1:100, 60)
B <- sample(1:100, 50)
C <- sample(1:100, 75)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ggraph we must use scale_size() for nodes and scale_edge_width() for edges to harmonize proportions. Point sizes in ggplot are scaled by their radius already:

[Does size for ggplot2::geom_point() refer to radius, diameter, area, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067450/does-size-for-ggplot2geom-point-refer-to-radius-diameter-area-or-somethin)

so no transformations are necessary, unless you want the point size to be proportional to the edge width by area.

Build a tbl_graph with your samples

```
#edges are determined by length of intersection
edges <- data.frame('from'=c('A','B','C'),'to'=c('B','C','A'),
'weight'=c(length(intersect(A,B)),length(intersect(B,C)),length(intersect(C,A))))

#nodes are weighted by the length of the sample
nodes <- data.frame('name'=c('A','B','C'),size=c(length(A),length(B),length(C)))

tbl_graph <- tbl_graph(nodes=nodes,edges=edges)
```

Now, if you build the network directly with these sizes, the distances between nodes will be decided automatically, and most ggraph layouts set distances between nodes between 0 and 1, resulting in a crowded graph with oversized edges and nodes. If the distance between nodes is not important, we can simply use a scaling factor to scale the node sizes and edge widths down to fit the graph.

In order to harmonize width and sizes, we scale the range of the edge widths to the min and max of the edge widths, and scale node sizes to the min and max of the nodes' sizes, multiplied by 2, as the nodes are scaled by diameter. This way, node sizes and edge widths are scaled to their actual values, rather than decided by the layout. I also include here additional annotation methods to show the sizes of the nodes and edges. node_point shape=21 is the empty circle. Good luck!

```
scale_factor = 0.1
ggraph(tbl_graph) + geom_edge_link(aes(width=weight*scale_factor,label=weight),label_dodge=unit(-4,'mm'),angle_calc='along') + 
scale_edge_width(range=c(min(edges$weight)*scale_factor,max(edges$weight)*scale_factor)) + 
geom_node_point(aes(size=size * scale_factor),shape=21) + scale_size(range=c(min(nodes$size)*scale_factor*2,max(nodes$size)*scale_factor*2)) + 
theme_linedraw() + geom_node_text(aes(label=paste(name,':',size)),nudge_x=-0.1)
```

[resulting ggraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRd0.png)